# How to control the bitrate of youtube video on the go

Tags: php, youtube, bitrate

I am using PHP as server side scripting. I want to know , How to control the quality of a video using php.
Here is what i want to do.

I will capture a video using any device and upload to server, and while retrieving the video
i would like to provide **some options for the quality of a video to be displayed**. Similar to how youtube provide some settings 240p,260p,480p etc

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use software such as wowza to do converting on the fly (http://www.wowza.com/)

Alternatively you could convert your uploaded video (straight after upload) by shelling out to ffmpeg.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $input -b 128k $output", $output);
```

and then link to the different video files depending on selected bitrate.